# How to prevent page from jumping on menu open?

Tags: html, css

I have a css menu and would like to open it without moving the rest of the page.

Here is the current fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/50c1Lhe7/

**HTML**

```
<div class="logo-container large-6 columns">
    <div class="large-3 columns">IMAGE</div>
    <div class="large-9 columns">
        <a href="/" rel="home">
            <h1 class="site-title">WORDS</h1>
            <div class="site-slogan">MORE WORDS</div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<nav id="nav" role="navigation">
    <a href="#nav" title="Show navigation">☰ MAIN MENU</a>
    <a href="#" title="Hide navigation">☰ MAIN MENU</a>
    <ul id="main-menu" class="main-nav left">
        <li class="first leaf" title=""><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
        <li class="expanded has-dropdown" title=""><a href="/" title="">About</a> 
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li class="expanded show-for-small"><a href="/" title="">About</a></li>
                <li class="first leaf"><a href="/">About</a></li>
                <li class="leaf" title=""><a href="/" title="">Our Team</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="leaf" title=""><a href="/" title="">Publications</a></li>
        <li class="leaf" title=""><a href="/" title="">Events</a></li>
        <li class="leaf active" title=""><a href="/" title="" class="active">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="last leaf"><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**SCSS**

```
#nav{
    display: none;
    width: 45%;
    height: 55px;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    #main-menu {
        ul { float: none; }
        li.expanded.show-for-small { display: none !important; }
    }
    #main-menu{
        margin-top: 21px;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100vw;
    }
}
#nav > a{
    display: none;
}
#nav li  {
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
#nav > ul{
    height: 3.75em;
}
#nav > ul > li {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#nav li ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}
#nav li:hover ul,
#nav li:focus ul { display: block; }
    #nav {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 999;
        display: block;
    }
    #nav:not( :target ) > a:first-of-type,
    #nav:target > a:last-of-type { display: block; }
    #nav > ul {
        height: auto;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #nav > ul { left: 0; }
    #nav:target > ul { display: block; }
    #nav > ul > li {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
        padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    #nav > ul > li.first.leaf.active { padding-top: 5px; }
    #nav li ul { position: static; }
```

Since the menu works by targetting the nav id, whenever the menu is clicked to open it drops down to the nav section. How would I change this so that it can be clicked and open without moving to the section? If this can be done easier with javascript please let me know.

Comment: The page is moving because the menu has lots of missing styles. And when you click to open the menu, the hidden elements will take up space that wasn't taken before. Thus, the page move

Comment: I simplified the styles to post a quick demo but the issue is still the same. When you click the menu it jumps to the #nav section because that's what is linked in the a tag. My question is if it's possible to open the menu without this jump, so the menu would load without moving the rest of the page down.

Comment: Apparently you can avoid the jump by a clever use of `position:fixed`. Take a look at [this cool demo](http://csscience.com/css3-tabs/), example 3 uses `:focus` and doesn't jump. I didn't check if you could adapt this technique for your code though.

Comment: The *jump* is the common problem for using :target for menu, suggest to use checkbox instead see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qn5o0a05/), it also works on more browsers.

Comment: The jump happens because `#` is pointing to `<a name="">` (the empty name isn't an accident). When no `<a>` element with the corresponding name is found, it jumps to the start of the page.

Comment: @Pangloss Yeah, an hidden checkbox before the `<div>` with an `id` set, and using a `<label>` with the `for` attribute to the same value is a great idea. I've done similar things with that trick.

Comment: I converted my comment into an answer below - with demo based on your html markup, see if it works for you, leave your comments for any questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ***jump*** is a common problem for using `:target` for menu, suggest to use `checkbox` instead, it also works on more browsers. Simplified demo follows.

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jLg5vsjo/)**

```css
/*main menu*/
nav {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
.menu-label {
    display: block;
    background: yellow;
}
.main-nav {
    display: none;
}
.menu-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.menu-checkbox:checked + .main-nav {
    display: block;
}
/*sub menu*/
.dropdown {
    display: none;
}
.main-nav li:hover .dropdown{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <label for="menu-1" class="menu-label">☰ MAIN MENU</label>
    <input id="menu-1" class="menu-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
    
    <ul id="main-menu" class="main-nav left">
        <li class="first leaf" title=""><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
        <li class="expanded has-dropdown" title="">
            <a href="/" title="">About</a> 
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li class="expanded show-for-small"><a href="/" title="">Sub menu 1</a></li>
                <li class="first leaf"><a href="/">Sub menu 2</a></li>
                <li class="leaf" title=""><a href="/" title="">Sub menu 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="leaf" title=""><a href="/" title="">Publications</a></li>
        <li class="leaf" title=""><a href="/" title="">Events</a></li>
        <li class="leaf active" title=""><a href="/" title="" class="active">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="last leaf"><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```