# Responsive navigation menu with hiding on small screens in pure CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I want to create a simple navigation menu with a special feature:

- On a desktop browser it shows as a bar like "item1 | item2 | item3"
- On a mobile browser it shows a button. When tapping on it, it shows the menu as stack

I'm searching a solution without Javascript. I know about media queries in CSS but I don't know how to add a menu with this requirement.

This is the menu for example:

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="item1.html">item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="item2.html">item2</a></li>
        <li><a href="item3.html">item3</a></li>
        <li><a href="item4.html">item4</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```css
/* default for all browsers */
nav>ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #3d3d3d;
}
nav>ul>li>a {
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
    /* mobile */
    /* WHAT NOW? */
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 361px) {
    nav>ul>li {
        /* bar layout */
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1fg4qkx5/

Comment: I think for a good, portable solution that works on any mobile browser, you need at least a little bit of script to toggle a class to show the menu. I've tried this before in pure CSS, but it gave issues on some browsers.

Comment: You have to create another menu like a dropdown for your mobile. Then set hide for one and visible for the other one. It's the easier way. IMHO

Comment: How to make a dropdown menu with pure css - http://stackoverflow.com/a/31147427/483779

Answer (score 1):

i have edited your jsfiddle and found a rather "Simple" solution for you,

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1fg4qkx5/2/)

I have not (yet) found a way to do this completely without javascript to catch the button click.

to post out the results here:

---

### HTML

```
<nav>
    <button class='hide-lg right'>
        &#9776;
    </button>
<ul>
    <li><a href="item1.html">item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="item2.html">item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="item3.html">item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="item4.html">item4</a></li>
</ul>
```

### css

```
/* default for all browsers */
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body{
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

button{
  border:1px solid gray;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
}

.show{
  display: inline-block;
}
.right{
  float:right;
}
nav{
  background-color: #3d3d3d !important;
  color: #ffffff;
  height:auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
nav>ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
}
nav>ul>li>a {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  .hide-lg{
    display:inline-block;
  }
  ul{
    display: none;
  }
  /* mobile */
  /* WHAT NOW? */
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 361px) {
  .hide-lg{
    display: none !important;
  }
  nav>ul{
    display: block;
  }
  nav>ul>li {
    /* bar layout */
    display: inline-block;
  }
  nav>ul>li>a{
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

### Javascript/jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
      $('ul').toggleClass('show');
  });
});
```

I hope you find my answer helpfull,
Giovanni